# Unstable WiFi connection Ubuntu 14.04 - Lenovo G40-70 rtl8723be

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, realtek-wireless

This is annoying, my internet connection drops after a few minutes and I have to restart my Lenovo G40-70 because restarting the network manager doesn't work.I also tried the solutions from related solved questions but none of them fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing Wi-Fi drivers manually? Perhaps you should check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238087) forum post out (if you haven't already done so).

Comment: Please follow http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 and paste the output here for further diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a better driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

And reboot

Comment: Thank you so much, now my internet connection seems to be working properly.