# RTL8723be wifi working really slow

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, 16.04

Ok been on this for a couple of days.Initially when I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts wifi was not working at all.But after some fixes I made it work although it's still not very stable and is slow.
I have tried in the following order:

1. Installing the new driver according to the first answer given on this page [Unstable WiFi connection Ubuntu 14.04 - Lenovo G40-70 rtl8723be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633200/unstable-wifi-connection-ubuntu-14-04-lenovo-g40-70-rtl8723be)
2. Installing another driver according to the first answer given on this page [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)
3. Than upgrading my kernel to 3.16.0-031600-generic.
4. Than applying `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` according to information given on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#rtl8723ae.2Frtl8723be

It's not that wifi is not working at all but it is working really slow to the point of frustation.
Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Output of `iw dev wlan0 station dump`:

```
Station c4:e9:84:87:e1:86 (on wlan0)
    inactive time:  48 ms
    rx bytes:   3331226
    rx packets: 15891
    tx bytes:   1163486
    tx packets: 4703
    tx retries: 0
    tx failed:  0
    signal:     -74 dBm
    signal avg: -73 dBm
    tx bitrate: 150.0 MBit/s MCS 7 40Mhz short GI
    authorized: yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:   long
    WMM/WME:    yes
    MFP:        no
    TDLS peer:      no
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 12/05/2015:

I've just upgraded to 16.04.Everything is working great except wifi.
Problem remains the same.Wifi remains connected but works really slow.Probably slower than before.So the outputs are:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

and of `iw dev wlan0 station dump` is:

```
Station c4:e9:84:87:e1:86 (on wlan0)
    inactive time:  2404 ms
    rx bytes:   1351602
    rx packets: 8268
    tx bytes:   524504
    tx packets: 1874
    tx retries: 0
    tx failed:  0
    signal:     -66 dBm
    signal avg: -66 dBm
    tx bitrate: 150.0 MBit/s MCS 7 40MHz short GI
    rx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s
    authorized: yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:   long
    WMM/WME:    yes
    MFP:        no
    TDLS peer:  no
```